# How to disable auto scaling in DynamoDB table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to test making way too many request to a DynamoDB table to trigger the exception `ProvisionedThroughputExceededException`.

For this I have to reach the capacity limit, so I need to create a table that doesn't auto-scale.

DynamoDB has [2 capacity modes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadWriteCapacityMode.html):

- *on-demand*: you don't specify any capacity, the table adapts to any traffic.
- *provisioned*: you specify your desired capacity, but can also auto-scale.

I'm using *provisioned* mode, but I don't know how to disable its auto scaling. On the table, **capacity settings**, I only have this:

[image]

There's this option of *I authorize DynamoDB to scale capacity using the following role*. But it's already set, I can't touch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable autoscaling by clicking the checkboxes above each of the units (`Read capacity` and `Write capacity`).

Once you uncheck these checkboxes, the textboxes above allow you to put a specific value for each type of credit unit.

[image: DynamoDB console]